# Contour clabels overlapping in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, inline, contour

I have a contour plot with clabels, but the labels are overlapping with one-another on a part with a higher contour gradient.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=150)
cnt = plt.contour(Te, ne, ion2, 16, cmap=plt.cm.inferno)
for c in cnt.collections:
    c.set_edgecolor("face")
plt.colorbar(cnt, label='Effective ionisation rate - $S_\\mathrm{iz}$ ($\\times$1e-14 m$^3$ s$^{-1}$)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.clabel(cnt, inline=1, fontsize=7, fmt='%1.1f', inline_spacing=5, use_clabeltext=False)
plt.xlabel('Electron temperature - $T_e$ (eV)')
plt.ylabel('Electron density - $n_e$ (m$^{-3}$)')
plt.ylim([1e17, 1e21])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Don’t label so many contours by passing the *levels* kwarg?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jody but I'd rather keep that number of contour lines on the right hand side. My ideal solution would be some way to move the labels on the left alternating up and down. Edit - also, in my ```plt.contour``` line I pass in the number 16 which is the number of levels, just without the ```levels=``` syntax in front of it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep that number of contour lines on the right hand side" .  I'm not suggesting changing the number of contours, I'm just suggesting that you only label every 5th one.  A whole bunch of labels is distracting, even if you didn't have an overlap problem.

Comment: Ah I see, apologies I misinterpreted what you'd written. This could work, although I would still rather have them all labelled and just move the labels I think, I disagree that it's distracting having them labelled, at least in this instance I don't think it is.

Comment: I somewhat suspect this is a bit of a bug in Matplotlib. Can you provide a self-contained example and open a report at matplotlib's issue tracker?

Comment: Actually, I've opened one.   https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22367

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak, I'll keep an eye on that